# Styled Text is Invalid

Tags: jasper-reports

I got this Text Field Expression:

```
"declared in the name of <style isBold=\"true\" isUnderlined=\"true\"> " + $F{owner.name} + "</style>"
```

`owner.name` contains characters such as : `.` and `&`

When I run my code in Java, the output is the same as the expression, the **bold** and **underline** didn't worked. Take not that I already checked the `isStyledText` in the Text Field's Properties.

Comment: You should post the whole textField's declaration

Comment: Is there any thrown error?

Comment: Are you sure you can put `style` elements into the text field expression? As of now I've merely used `style` elements in the text fields next to the expression applying to the whole content.

Comment: Pass the complete jrxml of your textField and an example of what the  $F{owner.name} contains

Answer (score 1):

Styled text is parsed as XML, so if you want to include a literal value in styled text you'll have to escape it according to XML rules.  In your case, the problem is `&` which cannot appear as such in XML.

One way to escape values for XML is to use JasperReports's `JRStringUtil`, like this:

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA["declared in the name of <style isBold=\"true\" isUnderlined=\"true\"> " + net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStringUtil.xmlEncode($F{owner.name}) + "</style>"]]></textFieldExpression>
```